# SQLite Inner Join not working converting from Access

Tags: sqlite

Could use some help converting this Access query to SQLite....

```
SELECT [Objects].[Object_ID], [Equation_Types].[Equation_Type], [Objects].[Dynamic], [Objects].[Visible], [Object_Types].[Object_Type], [DisplayFormats].[DisplayFormat]
FROM (((((Objects INNER JOIN Object_Transactions ON [Objects].[Object_ID]=[Object_Transactions].[Object_ID]) INNER JOIN Strings ON [Objects].[String_ID]=[Strings].[String_ID]) INNER JOIN Object_Types ON [Objects].[Object_Type_ID]=[Object_Types].[Object_Type_ID]) INNER JOIN DisplayFormats ON [Objects].[DisplayFormat_ID]=[DisplayFormats].[DisplayFormat_ID]) INNER JOIN (Service_Types INNER JOIN ((Header INNER JOIN Services ON [Header].[Header_ID]=[Services].[Header_ID]) INNER JOIN Transactions ON [Services].[Service_ID]=[Transactions].[Service_ID]) ON [Service_Types].[Service_Type_ID]=[Services].[Service_Type_ID]) ON [Object_Transactions].[Transaction_ID]=[Transactions].[Transaction_ID]) INNER JOIN Equation_Types ON [Object_Transactions].[Equation_Type_ID]=[Equation_Types].[Equation_Type_ID]
WHERE ((([Objects].[Dynamic])=True) And (([Objects].[Visible])=True) And (([Object_Types].[Object_Type])="DATA"));True) And (([Object_Types].[Object_Type])="DATA"));
```

Sorry for the formatting.

The inner most joins are not recognizing the columns.

```
INNER JOIN Transactions ON [Services].[Service_ID]=[Transactions].[Service_ID]) ON [Service_Types].[Service_Type_ID]=[Services].[Service_Type_ID]) ON [Object_Transactions].[Transaction_ID]=[Transactions].[Transaction_ID])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right hand side of an `INNER JOIN` clause must be a table, not a table expression.

Inner joins are commutative, so you can just drop all the parentheses.